# Angular : ViewEncapsulation.None

Tags: angular, typescript

I haven't understood what's the meaning of the property encapsulation inside @Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'az-manage',
  templateUrl: './manage.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./manage.component.scss']
})
export class ManageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this blog https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you leave the default encapsulation all your CSS rules for this component will have added **attribute selector** so they will look like this:

```
.yourclass[ngcomponent-0] {
  your set of rules
}
```

and the actual markup generated will look like this:

```
<yourcompoent ngcomponent-0=""></yourcompoent>
```

This way your CSS is strictly bound to your component, so it will not affect any other part of your app. If you do `ViewEncapsulation.NONE`, attribute selector won't be added, CSS will be global and will affect every other part of the app.

Disclaimer: I don't remember if it is ngcomponent-x or ngN-component or whatever - that does not matter - the rule is explained.